# Failed to create interpreter: Parameter safety_checks = '' declared in <<merged>> is invalid. '' is not a valid SafetyChecks

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

this is a fresh installation of both Pycharm and Anaconda. I created the first project, but when I tried to create an environment, I received this error:

```
CustomValidationError: Parameter safety_checks = '' declared in <<merged>> is invalid.
'' is not a valid SafetyChecks
Valid choices for safety_checks: 'disabled', 'warn', 'enabled'
```

Wondering if this is a permissions issue. Please see the attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exactly similar problem.

I solved it by running PyCharm as Administrator mode. Apparently there was indeed a permissions issue.

**To do that, right click PyCharm > *Run as Administrator*.**

And then to re-create a new conda environment:

1. Open PyCharm.
2. Go to File > Settings > Project:[Project_Name] > Project Interpreter
3. Click on the small settings button on the right.
4. Select Add.
5. Specify the name of the environment and then click OK.

[image: PyCharms settings window]